# Need help identifying identifying exterior, in-ground valve related to residential swimming pool

Tags: plumbing, valve, pool, old-house, identify-a-tool

We have an inground pool at our house in the US that was built sometime in the 70s-80s.  Below the diving board is an unique and currently unused area covered with some 2x8s or 2x10s.  Beneath the wood is sand with a metal pipe sticking out of it.  The pipe appears to be 1.25-1.5" diameter and has a captive metal rod coming out of it.  The metal rod cannot turn in the "seated" position, it must be lifted.  The rod lifts a couple inches and, while lifted, will rotate 360°.  There is enough movement/play in the lifted rod that it does not feel like this rod will unscrew from anything below.  When lifted as high as it will go, the rod encounters extremely firm and immediate resistance, like whatever is at the bottom of the rod is too large to fit thru an opening.

There is a corresponding pipe coming out of the wall in the basement, but there is a smaller pipe (maybe 1/2-3/4") sticking out of it with an elbow and a cap.  The smaller pipe can only move up/down/left/right within the confines of the larger pipe, there is no movement when pushed/pulled.

For a home automation project, I would like to reuse this as a conduit for a single CAT6 cable, but I would like more information on the valve's purpose and if it's possible to remove the rod or smaller diameter pipe without having to dig.

Here is a link to a Google Photos album with a video of the pool side of the valve and some photos of the basement side of the valve... https://photos.app.goo.gl/xmiGRUDXdbGLNYdc9

Thanks much!

Comment: Are you sure this is the same pipe? If a old fill pipe how do you intend to remove the valve so you can run the cat6 wire if this would be allowed would be in article 680 of the National electric code for the US.

Comment: The video seems to show some sort of shut-off valve buried below the frost line; note how it seats and unseats from something. The stick is supposed to be a deep key. In your basement, try uncapping it slowly. If you smell mercaptan (gas odorant) then re-cap it quickly. If water starts dripping then you'll know it's a wat line.

Comment: nobody uses steel pipes for pool water, chlorine is too corrosive.

Comment: the small diameter pipe  will unscrew from whatever is at the other end  - use a pipe wrench... but first check that there's nothing in the small pipe.  given enough force the metal rod can be removed without digging, steel is stronger than dirt, so it will happen other stuff might break.

Comment: metal rod cannot turn?  how long was the wrench you used to try this?

Comment: My guess is it works like a bathtub stopper. It likely has a C-clip in the bottom of the pipe that catches a lip near the top of the tube. When it drops down, it stops flow (maybe a V shaped wedge at the bottom of the rod and pipe?). When you lift and rotate is sits up and allows water to pass through.